# Dynamically update ranks of elements in a Redis Sorted Set

Tags: go, redis, fifo

In my Go program, I'm working with a Redis Sorted Set called `MyEntries` that has three elements: `EntryA`, `EntryB` and `EntryC` with rankings **1**, **2** and **3** (and so on..).

It's all ordered and elements are unique (that's why I'm **not** using a LIST).

But then the problem is when ranking order is obviously no longer the case **if** one element is removed! For example, if I remove `EntryB`, `EntryC` would still have ranking 3 (instead of 2).

I know I could basically query by index, since the index number does dynamically change. But I just found out there's, unfortunately, no way in Redis to query index by element name.

Would you please help me solve this issue? Is there any way in Redis to dynamically update rankings in Sorted Sets if one element is removed?

PS I'm building a FIFO queuing program that enables users to *also* remove elements out of the queue (besides that the oldest leaves first).  You'd also like to know what's your *position* in the queue (that's why I'm facing this ranking update issue).

Comment: what do you mean by `no way in Redis to query index by element name` ? What will be your query ? get the ranking of a given element ?

Comment: So here they're discussing that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899111/get-the-index-of-an-item-by-value-in-a-redis-list

And I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation either.. (Commands reference page)

Comment: what about `zrank` https://redis.io/commands/zrank

Comment: I'm using it. But then that brings me to the problem I describe above! What if I remove one element.. the ranking of the newer elements should change!

Comment: i added a possible solution as an answer which covers adding, removing, ranking, all list etc .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting ranking you may put the `score` which identifies ranking.

If user `a` has score of `100`, `b` has score `200` etc..

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd mysort 100 a 200 b 300 c 500 d 50 e
(integer) 5
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange mysort 0 -1 withscores
 1) "d"
 2) "500"
 3) "c"
 4) "300"
 5) "b"
 6) "200"
 7) "a"
 8) "100"
 9) "e"
10) "50"
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank mysort d
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank mysort e
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> zrem mysort b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank mysort e
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrem mysort d
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange mysort 0 -1 withscores
1) "c"
2) "300"
3) "a"
4) "100"
5) "e"
6) "50"
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank mysort e
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd mysort 500 q 25 f 350 p
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange mysort 0 -1 withscores
 1) "q"
 2) "500"
 3) "p"
 4) "350"
 5) "c"
 6) "300"
 7) "a"
 8) "100"
 9) "e"
10) "50"
11) "f"
12) "25"
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank mysort q
(integer) 0
```

In here you keep adding your element into sorted set with their scores, the higher score means the lower ranking - highest score will be `0` when you use `zrevrank`. when you remove the highest scored element with `zrem` then the second highest scored element will be highest ranked with the value of `0`.

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)